# How do I prevent this struct from leaking memory in a JNI call?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing a Java wrapper library to get information about the power status of the system.  What cleanup code is needed to prevent any memory leaks?

Relevant method:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jcmapi_powermanagement_SystemPowerStatus_getACLineStatus(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS status;
    GetSystemPowerStatus(&status);
    return status.ACLineStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't jiggle with objects, there is no cleanup to do. In your example, the struct is not leaked. It is created on stack when the native method is called, and released automatically in return.